# jquery selector for select hidden field value div under a parent div

Tags: jquery

I have svg image slider. I want to show an image in a small popup as image shown in google news section in mouseover event.

I have a parent `div` which has a class called `class="image-scroll-container"`. And under this I have a list of `divs`. Each `div` contain a `svg image` and has a class called `class="svg-image"` and this `div` also contain a `hidden field` named as `name="svg"`.

So I want to pick this value for each image on mouseover event. So plz tell me how do I get the hidden field value using jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Maby this works (sorry I can't test it right now):

```
$('div.svg-image [name="svg"] :hidden').val();
```

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the following code, the answer would look like this:

```
<div class="image-scroll-container">
    <div class="svg-image" onmouseover="getHiddenField(this)">
        <svg>...</svg>
        <input type="hidden" name="svg" value="123456">
    </div>
    <div class="svg-image" onmouseover="getHiddenField(this)">
        <svg>...</svg>
        <input type="hidden" name="svg" value="azertty">
    </div>
    ...
</div>

<script>
    function getHiddenField(element){
            alert($(element).children("input:hidden").val());
    }
</script>
```

Next time please provide HTML example!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the mouseover event on the dic with the `svg-image` class, you could something like this:

```
$('.svg-image').mouseover(function(){

    // get value of input field. 
    // If container div has more than 1 input, you'll need to refine the selector.

    var value = $(this).find('input').val();   

});
```